# Telerik winforms RadDropDownListElement on RadRibbonBarGroup

Tags: winforms, telerik, telerik-radribbonbar, raddropdownbutton

I am facing an issue with RadDropDownListElement when I use it on RadRibbonBarGroup. When RadRibbonBarGroup is in collapsed on minimized mode, it converts each RibbonBarGroups into a  drop down buttons. So The problem is when I click on dropdownlist control it will get hide behind the ribbon bar on first click and when I click on it again it will show up above the radribbonbar.

Now when user closes the dropdownlist and click on it again it will appears in front of ribbonbar.

I tried to set RadDropDwonList's z-index to any number but it never worked for me. I don't know what need to be know to fix this issue.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have tested this with the latest version but I was unable to put the popup of RadDropDownList behind the ribbon. Here is a video of my attempt: http://screencast.com/t/DtjAMAYb5d . Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know, how were you able to make it work. I will also try to create a poc and will see if I can reproduce it or not? But I couldn't make it work on my current project. Thanks checho for your efforts.

Comment: For your information, I am using version v2014.1.402.40 Dev.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this with the Q1 2014 version and indeed there is an issue in this case. In the [Telerik UI for WinForms release notes](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/winforms/release-history/ui-for-winforms-q2-2014), I have found the following item, which implies of your case: 
*The popup of a CommandBarDropDownList gets hidden behind the overflow button.*. I have also tested with the q2 and q3 2014 versions, and this is no longer an issue, so upgrade is your way out :).